# How must I serve json data from php using apache such that dojo can accept it?

Tags: php, json, apache, dojo

I am trying to serve a json data file using content from a database to be used by a dojo widget (`dijit.form.FilteringSelect`). All the parts seem to be working, but when it's all wired up the ajax call for data returns a 500 error.

In php, I am serving the file using

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Accessing the URL using a browser (Chromium or Iceweasel) initiates a download of the file. The data looks fine. If I save the file back to the server and serve it as a static json file it works just fine.

However if I connect the widget to the data file that is processed by PHP and watch the network connections using Firebug or the Chromium dev tools, the data call returns a 500 error from apache. Looking at the apache log files there is no mention of a php issue, just a one liner showing the request was returned 500.

This happens whether I use a `.php` file extention or add a special handler for the `.json` file to be processed by PHP. Again, calling the URL directly returns 200 and the correct data.

What do I need to change in either my PHP code or the apache server so that it will successfully send data requested by dojo?

Comment: Do you pass any parammeters by GET or POST? 500 error code is Internal Server Error and its commonly caused by errors in code, be by a missing value or whatever.

Comment: @rcdmk: No, no parameters are being passed. An inspection of the headers sent by the browser shows it is sending a GET request with no values. The apache access log confirms this that just the file name is being requested. The script does not expect any parammeters, nor would it fail if they were present, nor does it give any errors when called manually with or without get/post data.

Comment: When you inspect the direct request & the ajax request do you see a difference in the headers?

Comment: Are you using some king of rewriting or redirection with .htaccess?

Comment: @Yaniro: Yes. When the ajax is made it has `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` as one of the request headers. I have other scripts being called via AJAX returning other data that get sent this header that do not return errors, it is only the json one being problematic. I have tried adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');` to the php script but no change.

Comment: @rcdmk: I have lots of rewrite rules but none that should be touching this request. I have tried turning `RewriteEngine off` for testing and deleting all the rules. It also gives the same error if I use `/test.json` as the URL and redirect it to my php script or if I call the php script as `/test.json.php` directly or if I use the `test.json` file name and add a php handler for it.

Comment: As a precaution, did you check that the path requested directly in the browser is the same as the one requested in the ajax?

Comment: @Yaniro: Yes, several different ways including copy/paste both directions and doing diff on the sever access logs. It's definitely not a path error.

Comment: Is there a chance of you using the `IP address` in one and the `localhost` name on the other? This can cause cross domain blocking (Same Domain Policy).

Comment: @rcdmk: No, same domain for both calls. And wouldn't that cause the browser to throw the error, not the server to return 500?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Can you reproduce this behavior in any online tool like http://codepad.viper-7.com/ for us to test and see the code? We need more information.

Comment: @rcdmk: Thanks for the effort. I finally traced this to a conditional include error in a library that was auto-included via PHP's auto_include system that was behaving differently for XMLHttpRequest than for normal calls. The library was trapping the error message which was why it was so hard to debug.

Comment: Good. Mark your anwser as the solution. It can help others with the same problem.

Comment: @rcdmk I will just waiting on the timeout so I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development server being used here had the PHP `auto_prepend_file` value set to include some libraries that included a page templating engine. While this was not causing any issues when the page was called normally (and no templating was being done since the functions were not being called), an error in the included code was causing a bad library to be loaded if the `X-Requsted-With` GET request header was set to `XMLHttpRequest`, hence the 500 error only when called from the AJAX call. Additionally the library was trapping the errors it generated which is why the php errors weren't showing up anywhere.

Otherwise the header shown in the question is correct.

Answer (score -1):

application/json is a valid header preferred by all common browsers, you may have some error in your json, try checking your json data in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ maybe that helps

Comment: Thanks, but I already ruled out the json being valid or invalid in the question. The data served when I make the request manually is valid JSON and my app works. When the request is made via AJAX it gets a 500 error and NO DATA IS TRANSFERED to be valid or invalid json.

Comment: I meant maybe you dump a valid json header and non-valid json content, that may cause an error I guess. Otherwise, it can rather be your backend causing internal error. By the way, do you use jquery ajax? It can read JSON normally if header is dumped, maybe you have to specify something additional when requesting your json if you use simple ajax. Try using jQuery $.post or $.get methods and log a json object to console (console.log(response)) from callback param... Also I assume it can be your mod_rewrite causing this..

Comment: Thanks for trying but you clearly are not reading my question or don't understand the pieces involved. I am not using jQuery, I'm using dojo. And I've already addressed the issue with json content validity, as said in the question. I've also addressed the potential of this being a mod_rewrite issue in comments above.